# Gson deserialize not working properly

Tags: java, json, list, mapping, deserialization

I have a jsonarray formatted like this:

```
String jsonArray = {"myList":[{"code":"01","price":"2,3", "date":"21/12/2014"},{"code":"02","price":"3,4", "date":"26/12/2014"}]}
```

Mylist class is:

```
public class MyList {
    private String code;
    private String price;
    private String date;

    //..getter and setter
}
```

My non working "deserializator" is the following:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<MyList> list = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonArray, new TypeReference<List<MyList>>() { });
```

catching the following exception:

```
       org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
```

How can I solve that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd say you have to pass the value of `"myList"` to the mapper and not the root object - or maybe the root object plus the information to extract `"myList"` (I don't know Gson that well).

Comment: Solved, see my solution, hope it's the best practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my own working solution using Gson:

```
String jsonArray = {"myList":[{"code":"01","price":"2,3", "date":"21/12/2014"},{"code":"02","price":"3,4", "date":"26/12/2014"}]}

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

List<MyList> list = new ArrayList<MyList>();
try {
    JsonArray jArray = (JsonArray) parser.parse(jsonArray).getAsJsonObject().get("myList");

    for (JsonElement jObj : jArray) {
            MyList item = gson.fromJson( jObj , MyList.class);
            list.add(item);
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope it will be useful for other users!